# OracleDB NodeJS module connection pool not shared with a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, node-oracledb

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but what I'm trying to do seems like it should work.

I have the main project (server) and I'm trying to modularize various components of it, the first being a module (AQ) to send/receive messages on an Oracle queue using the Node OracleDB module.

The **server** project initializes the database connection pool with an alias of `dbpool1`. The alias name is stored in a configuration file read by the node-config module. Within the **server** project, there are some DB queries run, and then it calls `AQ.Receive()` from the `AQ` module. I'm importing the `AQ` module via an `import AQ from '@company/aq';` call at the beginning of the file.

Within the `AQ` codebase, the `Receive` function only contains an `OracleDB.getConnection(poolAlias)` call - I'm not initializing the database here as the assumption I'm making is the pool is initialized within the main project codebase before I call the `AQ` module. However, this call returns an error saying the pool is not found.

If I pass in the `pool` object created when the DB connection pool is created in the **server** project as a param to `AQ.Receieve`, a call to `pool.getConnection()` works correctly.

*Does an imported module share state/memory/whatever with the code doing the importing or do I need to complete reinitialize a connection (or pass it in as a parameter) to whichever module I'm importing?*

Comment: Node-oracledb should work as a singleton - there should be only one instance within a single Node.js process. A pool created in one module should be accessible in another (we added the pool cache to prevent you from having to create your own module for this). I'm guessing there's a timing issue (you're trying to access the pool before it's done being created). Are you awaiting the call to create the pool before you continue processing? If so, it may be a config issue (you tried to use a given alias but it didn't work). After the pool is created, use `console.log(pool.poolAlias)` to check.

Comment: We haven't looked deeply into ECMAScript modules and node-oracledb, but the basic thought was that sharing of C structures, e.g the connection pool, wasn't going to work across modules the way it does with standard `require()` modules.